# How to calculate Proportion in R in table or graph

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a following dataframe in R.

```
Batch_No   Type   Done    Error1     Error2    Error3    Error4
B-1        High   1       No         Yes       No        Yes
B-2        Mid    0       Yes        Yes       No        Yes
B-3        Mid    1       Yes        Yes       Yes       Yes
B-4        High   0       No         Yes       No        Yes
B-5        High   1       No         No        No        No
B-6        High   1       Yes         No        No        No
```

First, I want to aggregate the `Error` count in the following format. (Note - I have considered all count but I need to filter based on `Type` where `Type` = `High` and `Done` = `1`)

Required Format:

```
Error       Excl_Count   Excl_Count_%    Error1   Error2    Error3    Error4
No Error    1            50.00%          0        0         0         0      
Error1      1            50.00%          3        2         1         2        
Error2      0            0.00%           2        4         0         4
Error3      0            0.00%           1        1         1         1
Error4      0            0.00%           2        2         1         4
Total       2            100.00%         7        8         3         11
```

Once I create the above mentioned detaframe, I want to stimulate based on the proportion of error that If I resolve `Error1` then what is the expected number of count will not have any error considering the proportion of other errors.

For Example, If I resolve the following error by x%.

- Error1 = 25%
- Error2 = 50%
- Error3 = 0%
- Error4 = 10%

Required Output (Note - Numbers are dummy in Additional_No_Error)

```
Error       Excl_Count   Excl_Count_%    Error1   Error2    Error3    Error4    Additional_No_Error
No Error    1            50.00%          0        0         0         0         2
Error1      1            50.00%          3        2         1         2         2
Error2      0            0.00%           2        4         0         4         1
Error3      0            0.00%           1        1         1         1         0
Error4      0            0.00%           2        2         1         4         1
Total       2            100.00%         7        8         3         11        6
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @PierreGramme - I have tried `dplyr::summarise`.

Comment: I think PierreGramme was asking you to show code that you tried, not just a function included somehow in that code. It's often better to help you with your own code, since it might work better into the rest of your project flow. (It also can be useful at times to demonstrate that SO is not a free-code service.)

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example?